# What default file properties are selected by the RTC SCM command line client?

Tags: rational-team-concert

RTC (Rational Team Concert) provide a "source control command-line interface (CLI)", where the basic command is 'scm'.

We're currently using version "6.0.2" on Linux (64 bit).

Where a file is added into RTC, it acquires a set of associated properties, such as: jazz.executable, jazz.mime, jazz.read-access, jazz.encoding, jazz.line-delimiter. My primary interest is the "jazz.line-delimiter".

I know that I can modify the default file properties through a "magic.properties" file:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYMRC_5.0.2/com.ibm.team.scm.doc/topics/t_magicproperties.html

But... what is the default?

I've seen this mentioned, but not really explained, on IBM web help:

- If the CLI does not recognize a file type, it is treated as a binary
  file
- By default, when you share a project or check in a new file, Rational Team Concert™ source control examines the content and sets the line delimiter property of the file to the value PLATFORM.

Answer (score 0):

> But... what is the default?

One possible way to see the default for a given file would be to:

- *not* modify those properties through a magic file,
- show those properties, as seen in "[show properties example](https://jazz.net/help-dev/clm/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.team.scm.doc%2Ftopics%2Fshow_properties_ex.html)"

That is:

```
scm show prop -r ella abc10.txt
D:\Trash_Testing\Ella\abc5\abc10.txt
  jazz.encoding       - Cp1252
  local.encoding      - Cp1252
  jazz.executable     - false
  jazz.line-delimiter - Platform
  jazz.mime           - text/plain
  jazz.read-access    - Component scoped
```

From [scm cli on properties](https://jazz.net/help-dev/clm/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.team.scm.doc%2Ftopics%2Fr_scm_cli_on_properties.html):

> ### `jazz.line-delimiter`
>
> Indicates the line delimiter. May be one of:
>
> - **platform** – Indicates that the file should be given the **platform-specific line delimiter on load/accep**t.
> - **none** – Indicates that the file should not have its line delimiters changed on load/accept.
> - **crlf** – Indicates that the file should always have Windows-style line delimiters.
> - **lf** – Indicates that line-feeds should be used as line delimiters.
> - **cr** – Indicates that carriage returns should be used as line delimiters.

Comment: Noted, but I don't even know what characteristics of the "given file" drive the calculation of the default properties: Its filename? Its actual byte-by-byte content? I would like to understand the default behavior, such that I can trust that my team will get the 'right' properties for a mixture of files (mostly, source code and configuration files). It looks like, since the default behavior is vague (???), my only viable route to controlling this, is to invent and share a 'magic.properties' with a file-name-pattern-to-chosen-property for every file we are liable to encounter.

Comment: @WilliamEllis Agreed. I was just trying to address your "what is the default?" initial question.